# Picking up configuration properties from command line when launching jar from command line

Tags: java, heroku, vert.x

I an trying to launch a vert.x example both locally and on Heroku (using Procfile):

`java -Dhttp.port=$PORT -jar myapp.jar`

I experience that the property (http.port) is not set and thus not accessible to my program.

Reading the PORT environment variable using System.getenv() works, but is not a 'best practice'.

Why? What can I do?
Ove

Comment: How do you try to get the value of `http.port`? With `System.getProperties().get("http.port")` or with some vert.x internal magic?

Comment: I'm using vert.x magic: config().getInteger("http.port", 8080)

Comment: I'm not very much into vert.x but from this page (http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-config/groovy/) I think you need to setup a config retriever with the `sys` type: `def sysPropsStore = [ type:"sys" ]` and use this to lookup the config options. You can probably use the default config retriever as it should contain the system properties as well.

Comment: Why is using `System.getenv()` not a best practice? it's the most authoritative way to get the value of `$PORT`?

Comment: @codefinger because you're tied to provide the setting as OS environment variable. If you're using a config retriever, you can provide the setting as system property, by a properties file or as environment variable as well. This may be useful for different deployment scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

As @dpr points out ConfigRetriever is the way to go.

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
// Get the system property store (type = sys)
    val sysPropsStore = ConfigStoreOptions().setType("sys")
    // Add system property store to the config retriever options
    val options = ConfigRetrieverOptions().addStore(sysPropsStore)
    // And create a ConfigRetriever
    val retriever = ConfigRetriever.create(vertx, options)

    // Set the default port
    var httpPort: Int = 8080

    retriever.getConfig { ar ->
        if (ar.failed()) {
            // Failed to retrieve the configuration
        } else {
            val config = ar.result()

            if (config.containsKey("http.port")) 
                httpPort = config.getInteger("http.port")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Was this in your verticle `start()`, or where, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to define a json file and add all configuration related  vertx in it.

Pass config.json as argument while starting your application.

Here is the example :

> Config.json file

```
{
  "port": 8090
  // you can add other stuff over here
}
```

Pass a config.json as argument while running your application

> java -jar myapp.jar --conf=/path to your config.json

So you can read this json file in your main Verticle

```
 public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

 @Override
  public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {

   JsonObject data = this.config(); 

  // read port and other configuration related stuff from JsonObject 
 }
}
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: It might, and I am aware of this method. Problem is that Heroku assigns a random port.